# TextField number input using Arabic keyboard

Tags: swift, input, int, uitextfield, arabic

We are using few inputs in our app that use number pad type of keyboard. We are storing that values as Int.

Few days ago we encountered an error with one of our app users which uses Arabic keyboard. When trying to save input to database we encounter error since input is in Arabic symbols and doesn't get recognised as Int.

I wonder how you guys solve this kind of problems. I was thinking of converting input value like this so I created a little extension for String class:

```
func convertToNumber() -> Int {

    let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN")
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = locale

    let number = formatter.numberFromString(self)
    let returnNumber = Int(number!)

    return returnNumber
}
```

Is there any other better approach?

Comment: You can limit input text only as numbers. one way is to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: `, then check if incoming strign is a number(not text not any other unicode etc) and return bool accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I used the code below to convert from Arabic numbers "١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠" to English numbers "1234567890" i'm returning the value as string so maybe this is the difference.

If you still need to return an Int value try to change the code:

```
let returnNumber = Int(number!)
```

to

```
if Int(number!) != nil {
 return Int(number!)
}
else{
 return -1 //here you can return a value that you can check to decide    if an error happen or no.
}
```

Here is my working code:

```
extension String {
func arabicNumberToEnglish() -> String{

    //if number start with zero then Formatter.number(from: self) will remove it, 
   //so we need to know how many leading zero contain in the string 
   //so that we can add them before the return
    var leadingZero: String = ""

    func getLeadingZero(_ value: String)
    {

        if value.hasPrefix("0") || value.hasPrefix("٠") {
            leadingZero = leadingZero + "0"
            var newValue = value
            newValue = String(newValue.characters.dropFirst())
            getLeadingZero(newValue)
        }
        else{
            return
        }


    }

    //calling the inline function to get the leading zeros count
    getLeadingZero(self)

    let Formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    Formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
    if let final = Formatter.number(from: self){
        // returning the final result after adding the leadingZero's to it.
        return leadingZero + "\(final)"

    }
    else{
        return self
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.